# Covariance between brownian bridge and its max.

Tags: stochastic-processes

Does anyone know how to compute $\text{Cov}[\max_{s\in [0,1]}B(s), B(t)]$ where $B(t)$ is the standard Brownian bridge on the interval $[0,1]$?

**Update.** I have found a paper that solves the problem: [On the maximum of the generalized brownian bridge (Beghin, Orsingher)](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDgQFjAA&url=http://www.researchgate.net/publication/236984395_On_the_maximum_of_the_generalized_Brownian_bridge/file/72e7e51aee2ba07219.pdf&ei=vptmU-bVBe-O7Qbel4DwBw&usg=AFQjCNHy9l_js-OioLuwZTVzfyjWkBu0FQ&bvm=bv.65788261,d.ZGU&cad=rja)

Comment: I haven't worked this out, but it should be possible to do this with Girsanov.  Use the fact that $B(t)$ solves $dB = - \frac{B}{1-t}dt + dW$ on $0 \leq t < 1$ and use Girsanov to rewrite this as a BM.  Since the joint distribution of BM and the maximum of BM is known, this reduces the problem to a (possibly computable) integral.

Comment: Thank you @ChrisJanjigian. Unfortunately I am a novice in the sector and a lot of literature is already present. Do you suggest any particular reference to look at?